# How to dynamically setting relative layout background images?

Tags: android, android-layout

How to dynamically setting relative layout background?
My relative layout at the top,can not be set the id

Comment: I'm not sure what this means: "My relative layout at the top,can not be set the id", but with Raghav Sood's solution you can use `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"  ... > </RelativeLayout>`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Say you have a relative layout with the ID `relativeLayout`. You can set the background by using:

```
RelativeLayout rLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);
Resources res = getResources(); //resource handle
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.newImage); //new Image that was added to the res folder

rLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
```

Comment: `getDrawable()` and `setBackgroundDrawable()` are deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Try this for Xamarin.Android (Cross Platform)

RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout (this);
Or
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)FindViewById (Resource.Id.relativeLayout);

relativeLayout.SetBackgroundDrawable (Resources.GetDrawable (Resource.Drawable.imageName));